# Can you Apparate to a place that you haven't been to?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition, magical-transportation

For instance, if a wizard has a magical photograph of a place, but has never been there physically, can he Apparate there by just focusing on the picture?

Comment: "***Why couldn’t Newt just Apparate to the USA? Why did he go by boat? JKR:** Apparition becomes increasingly risky over long distances. As with most magic, much depends on the skill of the spell-caster: Apparition requires knowledge of the terrain to which one is moving, or the ability to visualise it clearly. Cross-continental Apparition would almost certainly result in severe injury or death.*"

Comment: Highly related: [How did Harry and his friends know so many places to disapparate to?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161779/31394)

Comment: No, they have to have been there not only at least once, but also to remember the place clearly. Some of them keep videotapes of the places with a voiceover describing the smell, air and - wait, wrong teleportation reference.

Comment: @Valorum True, but it's not a strong 'No'...especially for short distance apparition... And theoretically, one could visualize a location by its photo..

Comment: @Simpleton Absolutely you can visualise a place by its photo. And personally if the description is good enough I can visualise it just in my mind. Whether anyone could do that in the universe of HP I don't know but point is you don't have to have been there to visualise it: and there are examples where this is shown in the books.

Comment: @Jenayah What makes you think they have to have been there? Can you not visualise a place from a picture or from a vivid description? I certainly can and many others can. There are examples where indeed Apparation to places previously unvisited occurs.

Comment: @Pryftan as pointed out by the "wait, wrong teleportation reference", I was making a joke referrencing another teleportation work, namely _Jumper_ by Steven Gould :p (the book, not the... debatable... movie)

Comment: @Jenayah Although I suspected something like that it doesn’t mean that I knew the reference; so ask yourself this: if I don’t know said story how would I understand the context when in HP you do have to visualise the place but you don’t have have been there? After all the very question questions that doesn’t it? So although I didn’t know what you had in mind my reply is a perfectly reasonable reply in that circumstance.

Comment: @Pryftan I didn't say otherwise :) this was merely a "reference joke" intended to make those who get it smirk a bit. Those who don't, get a great book to add to their to-read-list if they want to. In any case, I do admit that it wasn't so relevant with the question, and my apologies if you felt offended in any way :)

Comment: @Jenayah No offence taken :) I am sure it’s good but not for me; although I do love sci-fi and more so fantasy my real love is Tolkien. I also love specific eras in history and so read I also read non-fiction (not just history). As for OT comment? Couldn’t care less; I think the politics and comment police... Well at least on this community there are no elitists! That they are so strict and are afraid of fun I pity them but I also feel other things. The rpg community here is one such and if I could remove myself from that community I would. Ah well. No worries for your comment :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes, it seems possible to Apparate to a place you’ve never been.

Narcissa Apparates to Snape’s house, and Bellatrix follows her, trying to stop her sister from betraying the Dark Lord’s confidence. Bellatrix Apparated separately from Narcissa.

> “With a second and louder *pop*, another hooded figure materialised.
>
> ‘Wait!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 2 (Spinner’s End)*</sup></sub>

It’s very clear when Bellatrix arrives at Snape’s house, she didn’t know what to expect. She was surprised to see that Snape lived in such a place. In addition, she said she suspected none of her kind had ever set foot there, which she probably wouldn’t say if she herself had been there before.

> “He lives here?’ asked Bella in a voice of contempt. ‘*Here?* In this Muggle dunghill? We must be the first of our kind ever to set foot –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 2 (Spinner’s End)*</sup></sub>

She seems surprised as well as disdainful, so she probably had never seen Spinner’s End before.

Comment: Surely you'd know if you'd been there before?

Comment: This answer is authoritative since you speak from first-hand experience! :P +1!

Comment: @HarryWeasley Not only is Miss Bella here a formidable opponent ('answerer') but so too in the books. But it is amusing to consider that here the example of Bella herself was used; I never thought of that until I read your comment though I haven't a clue if I gave anything any thought at all on her answer, until now.

Answer (score 10):

There is clear canonical evidence that it is possible to apparate to a never-visited location.

**Goblet of Fire Chapter 6**

> “Where ’re Bill and Charlie and Per-Per-Percy?” said  George, failing
>   to stifle a huge yawn.
>
> “Well, they’re Apparating, aren’t they?” said Mrs.  Weasley, heaving
>   the large pot over to the table and  starting to ladle porridge into
>   bowls. “So they can  have a bit of a lie-in.”

It is apparent that they have never visited the location of the Quidditch World Cup, based on Mr. Weasely's later comments:

> So we had to find a nice deserted  moor, and set up as many
>   anti-Muggle precautions as  possible.

Why would they have previously been to the deserted moor?

> I believe there’s a  handy wood they’re using as the Apparition point.

Or why would they have ever been to the handy wood?

Furthermore, in that same discussion Charlie's failure is described:

> “Charlie had to take the test twice,” said Fred,  grinning. “He failed
>   the first time, Apparated five  miles south of where he meant to,
>   right on top of  some poor old dear doing her shopping, remember?”

Had Charlie ever previously visited the exact spot that he accidentally ended up in?

---

The Death Eaters were able to apparate to the graveyard when Voldemort regained his body, even though there is no reason why any of them would have been there before. It was clearly not their regular meeting place, as Voldemort states:

> “My father’s bone, naturally, meant that we would  have to come here,
>   where he was buried.

---

Ron as well apparated places he had never been to previously. When he rejoins Harry and Hermione in the Forest of Dean (Deathly Hallows Chapter 19) he tells them:

> I didn’t do it so well, Splinched myself again” — Ron  held up his
>   right hand to show two missing  fingernails; Hermione raised her
>   eyebrows coldly —  “and I came out miles from where you were. By the 
>   time I got back to that bit of riverbank where we’d  been ... you’d
>   gone.”

He had obviously never previously been to a place miles away from a riverbank that he had only visited for the first time when they were camping there.

Just a few pages later he describes how he apparated to multiple places he had never been before:

> “It sort of floated toward me,” said Ron, illustrating  the movement
>   with his free index finger, “right to my  chest, and then — it just
>   went straight through. It  was here,” he touched a point close to his
>   heart, “I  could feel it, it was hot. And once it was inside me I 
>   knew what I was supposed to do, I knew it would take  me where I
>   needed to go. So I Disapparated and came out on the side of a hill.
>   There was snow everywhere.
>
> “We were there,” said Harry. “We spent two nights  there, and the
>   second night I kept thinking I could  hear someone moving around in
>   the dark and calling  out!”
>
> “Yeah, well, that would’ve been me,” said Ron. “Your  protective
>   spells work, anyway, because I couldn’t see  you and I couldn’t hear
>   you. I was sure you were  around, though, so in the end I got in my
>   sleeping bag  and waited for one of you to appear. I thought you’d 
>   have to show yourselves when you packed up the  tent.”
>
> “No, actually,” said Hermione. “We’ve been  Disapparating under the
>   Invisibility Cloak as an extra  precaution. And we left really early,
>   because, as Harry  says, we’d heard somebody blundering around.”
>
> “Well, I stayed on that hill all day,” said Ron. “I kept  hoping you’d
>   appear. But when it started to get dark I  knew I must have missed
>   you, so I clicked the  Deluminator again, the blue light came out and
>   went  inside me, and I Disapparated and arrived here in  these woods.
>   I still couldn’t see you, so I just had to  hope one of you would show
>   yourselves in the end —  and Harry did. Well, I saw the doe first,
>   obviously.”

Of course it is possible that the Deluminator had something to do with it, but the Deluminator is an invention of Dumbledore's which means that the "magical technology" for apparating to unknown places must actually exist in some form.

(Snape also arrived at the Forest of Dean, and while it doesn't say explicitly that he apparated, it seems a pretty safe assumption that he did so.)

---

Dumbledore apparently apparated to Privet Drive the night he left Harry there.

**Philosopher's Stone Chapter 1**

> A man appeared on the corner the cat had been  watching, appeared so
>   suddenly and silently you’d  have thought he’d just popped out of the
>   ground.

Is there any reason why he would have previously visited it? Indeed we are immediately told:

> Nothing like this man had ever been seen on Privet  Drive.

This would not be true if this very man had been there previously (unless "seen" is taken quite literally and on his previous visit no one had seen him).

---

The Snatchers appeared mere moments after Harry used the tabooed name of Voldemort, which indicates that they apparated, yet they obviously hadn't previously visited whatever random location the trio was using as their current hideout.

---

Harry apparates to Shell Cottage despite never having been there before.

**Deathly Hallows Chapter 23**

> “Ron, catch — and GO!” he yelled, throwing one of the  wands to him;
>   then he bent down to tug Griphook out  from under the chandelier.
>   Hoisting the groaning  goblin, who still clung to the sword, over one 
>   shoulder, Harry seized Dobby’s hand and spun on the  spot to
>   Disapparate.
>
> As he turned into darkness he caught one last view of  the drawing
>   room: of the pale, frozen figures of  Narcissa and Draco, of the
>   streak of red that was  Ron’s hair, and a blur of flying silver, as
>   Bellatrix’s  knife flew across the room at the place where he was 
>   vanishing —
>
> Bill and Fleur’s . . . Shell Cottage . . . Bill and Fleur’s . . .
>
> He had disappeared into the unknown; all he could  do was repeat the
>   name of the destination and hope that it would suffice to take him
>   there. The pain in his  forehead pierced him, and the weight of the
>   goblin  bore down upon him; he could feel the blade of  Gryffindor’s
>   sword bumping against his back; Dobby’s  hand jerked in his; he
>   wondered whether the elf was  trying to take charge, to pull them in
>   the right  direction, and tried, by squeezing the fingers, to 
>   indicate that that was fine with him. ...
>
> And then they hit solid earth and smelled salty air.  Harry fell to
>   his knees, relinquished Dobby’s hand,  and attempted to lower Griphook
>   gently to the  ground.

---

When Harry and Dumbledore visit Slughorn's house, Harry asks why they didn't just apparate directly into the house.

**Half Blood Prince Chapter 4**

> “Because it would be quite as rude as kicking down  the front door,”
>   said Dumbledore. “Courtesy dictates  that we offer fellow wizards the
>   opportunity of denying  us entry. In any case, most Wizarding
>   dwellings are  magically protected from unwanted Apparators. At 
>   Hogwarts, for instance — ”
>
> “ — you can’t Apparate anywhere inside the buildings  or grounds,”
>   said Harry quickly. “Hermione Granger  told me.”

The implication here is that if not for special anti-apparition protection and courtesy, they could theoretically apparate directly into the house. Yet Dumbledore has presumably never been there before, as Slughorn says:

> I’ve  been on the move for a year. Never stay in one place  more than
>   a week. Move from Muggle house to Muggle house — the owners of this
>   place are on  holiday in the Canary Islands — it’s been very 
>   pleasant, I’ll be sorry to leave.

Comment: I do think though that the fact he landed somewhere else than intended is more of a consequence of the risks in the magic; that wasn't where he intended to go. It might be argued that it's much like the Floo Network: don't say it carefully enough you land elsewhere. How similar is *Diagonally* to *Diagon Alley* relative to *Knockturn Alley*? Yet where does Harry end up? I also think it's a stretch to say that Dobby transporting him to Shell Cottage is the same thing as Elf magic is different; maybe Harry *believed he had to*. Still a good answer.

Comment: As for Dumbledore's device I don't think you can count that either since there's much more to it than that. I'm not saying it's not relevant but there is certainly more to it. Severus of course could have been there but we can presume he hadn't. As for the Taboo I thought it means they can be tracked which might be closer to how the Deluminator works (maybe even using the same magic).

Comment: @Pryftan *I do think though that the fact he landed somewhere else than intended is more of a consequence of the risks in the magic; that wasn't where he intended to go.* Of course it wasn't where he intended to go. But he still ended up there despite (presumably) never having been there before. Thus, apparition is possible to unvisited places. *I also think it's a stretch to say that Dobby transporting him to Shell Cottage is the same thing as Elf magic is different;* It seems from the text that Harry was trying to apparate there himself, and it is unclear if Dobby took over or not.

Comment: @Pryftan *As for Dumbledore's device I don't think you can count that either since there's much more to it than that. I'm not saying it's not relevant but there is certainly more to it.* It seems that the device just showed him where to go. He still apparated without having been there before. *As for the Taboo I thought it means they can be tracked which might be closer to how the Deluminator works (maybe even using the same magic).* Yes, the taboo is a tracker. But once they find out where the people are they still apparate there despite it being a new place.

Comment: The point about the accidental location is my guess that there is more to it than that; I mean to say I'm not sure it counts the same. Observe that I agree with you that it's possible I'm just saying I'm not sure that's the best example. As for Dobby; well then what about the fact he took the others first? Remember this too: Harry couldn't have Apparated out of Malfoy Manor could he? They prevented that but Elf magic bypasses that doesn't it?

Comment: As for the device: well that's true but the point was it might have been more to it; I'm not saying it's the full story by any means - I'm just saying there *could* be more to it (whether there is or not I do not know nor care to speculate as speculation really is of little value). And the tracking: well yes you're right but I think I was going with there *possibly* being something different. In any case I already up voted you and as you might have noticed I gave other examples in my answer!

Comment: Oh and another example that might be an exception is to do with the Dark Mark. I would say though that both sides of the argument is part speculation and in either case it still is an example so I suppose that even if it’s different it’s still good for the answer. I would argue then that your answer has another interesting layer to it. That’s great.

Answer (score 6):

**It appears yes.**

I can think of some examples: the rock Harry and Dumbledore Apparate to to get to the cave for the Horcrux. Whilst discussing the Horcrux memory with Harry Dumbledore says this at one point:

> 'Correct,' said Dumbledore. 'I have been looking for a very long time. I think . . . perhaps . . . *I may be close to finding another one.* **There are hopeful signs.'**
>
> 'And if you do,' said Harry quickly, 'can I come with you and
>   help get rid of it?'

This strongly implies that Dumbledore has never been to the place; he knows about it because of Ms. Cole but nowhere in canon can I think of that suggests Dumbledore has actually been there; certainly he's never been to the cave and this suggests that he hadn't been by the cave either. And at this point he *believed he had found one and he saw hopeful signs* but that doesn't mean it is certain - yet (as we find out later it is although the original locket had been stolen). In the chapter *The Seer Overheard* there is this dialogue between Harry and Dumbledore:

> And then Harry remembered why he had been eager to come to Dumbledore's office in the first place. 'You've found one? You've found a Horcrux?'
>
> 'I believe so.'
>
> Rage and resentment fought shock and excitement: For several
>   moments, Harry could not speak.
>
> 'It is natural to be afraid,' said Dumbledore.
>
> 'I'm not scared!' said Harry at once, and it was perfectly true;
>   fear was one emotion he was not feeling at all. 'Which Horcrux is
>   it? Where is it?'
>
> 'I am not sure which it is — though I think we can rule out the
>   snake — but I believe it to be hidden in a cave on the coast many
>   miles from here, **a cave I have been trying to locate for a very long
>   time: the cave in which Tom Riddle once terrorized two children
>   from his orphanage on their annual trip; you remember?'**

It is true that he used the word **been** as in past tense but as a literal thinker I try remembering that most don't interpret things that way; even so though he hasn't been to the cave and would he have gone to the rock? I don't think that's really the case *because if he had he'd already been able to verify the cave is indeed there.*

> 'Yes,' said Harry. 'How is it protected?'
>
> 'I do not know; I have suspicions that may be entirely wrong.'
>   Dumbledore hesitated, then said, 'Harry, I promised you that you
>   could come with me, and I stand by that promise, but it would be
>   very wrong of me not to warn you that this will be exceedingly
>   dangerous.'

The above dialogue suggests that Dumbledore is still uncertain on the matter. And how do they get to the area? By Apparating:

> 'Professor,' said Harry quietly, as the gates at the bottom of the
>   drive came into view, 'will we be Apparating?'
>
> 'Yes,' said Dumbledore. 'You can Apparate now, I believe?'
>
> 'Yes,' said Harry, 'but I haven’t got a license.'
>
> He felt it best to be honest; what if he spoiled everything by
>   turning up a hundred miles from where he was supposed to go?
>
> 'No matter,' said Dumbledore, 'I can assist you again.'
>
> 'It will not be necessary for us to enter,' muttered Dumbledore,
>   glancing around. 'As long as nobody sees us go . . . now place your
>   hand upon my arm, Harry. There is no need to grip too hard, I am
>   merely guiding you. On the count of three . . . One . . . two . . .
>   three . . .'
>
> Harry turned. At once, there was that horrible sensation that he
>   was being squeezed through a thick rubber tube; he could not draw
>   breath, every part of him was being compressed almost past en-
>   durance and then, just when he thought he must suffocate, the in-
>   visible bands seemed to burst open, and he was standing in cool
>   darkness, breathing in lungfuls of fresh, salty air.

Harry then questions that the orphanage took the orphans there; Dumbledore explains not precisely: there is a little village by there and they were taken to the sea. Only strong mountaineers would have been able to get to the cave; boats would not work because the waves are too strong. Dumbledore expects that Riddle would have used magic to climb down and so only his two victims and he himself visited it at the time. Certainly Dumbledore had never been to the cave itself and given the obstacles to get to the cave it seems to me he had never been to the rock either. He certainly had been to the orphanage but nothing suggests he had been to exactly where they Apparated to. Is it close enough that it works fine? Possibly but I'll return to this when I discuss the Three D's.

Hermione and Harry Apparate to Godric's Hollow in Deathly Hallows; just like Harry was too young to really understand death when his parents were killed (thus at Godric's Hollow) I'm certain that Hermione had never been there either. Hermione certainly hadn't been around the graveyard as Hermione earlier questions whether his parents would be there:

> 'I'm sure it is,' said Hermione, her eyes upon the church. 'They
>   . . . they'll be in there, won't they? Your mum and dad? I can see
>   the graveyard behind it.'

There is no canon instance that I can think of where Hermione had been there at all and Harry hadn't been there since his parents were murdered yet they Apparated there.

**But what about the Three D's?**

> 'The important things to remember when Apparating are the three D's!' said Twycross. 'Destination, Determination, Deliberation!'
>
> 'Step one: **Fix your mind firmly upon the desired destination**,'
>   said Twycross. 'In this case, the interior of your hoop. **Kindly concentrate upon that destination now.**

There seems to be some ambiguity but at the same time there are examples where it's suggested someone Apparates to a place they've never been to before. But does concentrating on the destination mean visualising it? That isn't specified here (see below) and one could easily argue that it's the place whether they've been there or not. But then what about determination?

> 'Step two,' said Twycross, 'focus your determination to occupy
>   the visualised space! Let your yearning to enter it flood from your
>   mind to every particle of your body!'

So let's say it's more than the place name: it's what it looks like. Do you need to have been somewhere to visualise it in your head? I certainly don't if I've seen photos or videos of it - and I remember it well enough. I can also visualise places I've read enough about; and it can be sure that Hermione read about Godric's Hollow, for example.

What this comes down to is it is suggested that some have Apparated to places they've never been to (or if they have it's not been noted prior to it) but it does require visualising the place. But there are different ways to think of visualisation and in the case of what it looks like we don't even need to have been there do we? And as our Miss Bella above reminds us Bellatrix was surprised where Severus lived and they did Apparate there; and since Bella and Narcissa Apparate separately we cannot say she had ever been there. It seems to me then that yes you can Apparate to places you've not personally visited.

Finally it can be sure that Dobby had never been to Shell Cottage before taking everyone from Malfoy Manor there (or around it). But since Elf magic is different that might not count.